# Unity download from FTP

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ftp

I have a FTP that contains a bunch of files and it's protected by user and password.

I'm trying to pull an image from it and assign it to a geometry.

this is the code I'm using

```
 public static IEnumerator urlTexture(){
     string url = "ftp://username:password@HOST_IP/images/00013/01_01.jpg";
     Debug.Log ("Request sent");
     GlobalVariables.myUrl [1] = new WWW (url_left);
     yield return GlobalVariables.myUrl [1];
     }
```

This code works just fine whenever I pull an image from a http address without having to provide credentials. The credentials are correct but it's just not working.

If I get the Url[1].url and paste the string it returns in my browser (both firefox and chrome), it works perfectly.

any clue about why it's not working from Unity?

Thank you very much

Comment: What's `url_left`? I don't see that being declared anywhere, and I don't see `url` being used anywhere either?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read from WWW class description :

> Note: http://, https:// and file:// protocols are supported on iPhone. **ftp:// protocol support is limited to anonymous downloads only.** Other protocols are not supported.

Source: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html

Comment: Thank you, I totally missed that. Do you know any other way to pull data from an ftp with credentials I can look into?